# How to install OpenLayers plugin on QGIS 1.8?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

After having installed QGIS 1.8 I am not able to find the OpenLayers Plugin. In "the old days" I know I was supposed to check "add 3rd party repositories", but that button has disappeared. I tried adding the following repositories without luck:

```
http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed
..openlayers.org/api/2.12
..github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin.git
..github.com/nvkelso/qgis-openlayers-plugin.git
..plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml
..plugins.QGIS.org/plugins/plugins.xml
..github.com/openlayers/openlayers
```

I hope someone can help me locate the OpenLayers plugin as I desperately need it.

Comment: The following url is the new one used: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Answer (score 10):

I found the Github source https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin.  Since the repository address http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml listed on the Github page didn't work for me, I went ahead and cloned it. Then un-tar it and simply sudo mv it into the /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins directory. From there just enable it in the qgis "plugins -> manage plugins" dialogue.

Comment: Sourcepole's repository seems to be down currently.

Comment: Moving it to /home/your_name/.qgis/python/plugins/ also work.

Comment: As underdark mentioned, the Sourcepole repository is down at present. It's been up and down for the last couple of days.

Comment: I am sadly a little to new with the Qgis to understand what you mean by 'sudo mv' it. I suppose it is done in the terminal?

Comment: Hi, 'sudo mv' is a command in Ubuntu (or other Linux OS) that moves a file/directory with administrator permissions.  If you're using Windows, just drag/drop the unpacked file into your qgis plugins directory.  Or, by this time, the Sourcepole repo may be back up, rendering all this unnecessary.

Comment: The repo works again. Installed in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The plugin can now be downloaded from http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Qgis 1.8,(I'm working on windows 7...)
in the Python plugin installer I have add a repository : http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml 
and it's working, i can use know the openLayers plugin.

Thanks to underdark

Answer (score 2):

"

- Choose 'Plugins' menu -> 'Fetch Python Plugins...'
- Select the 'Repositories' tab at the top
- Add a new repository with the URL: http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml

This should allow you to find and install the OpenLayers plugin

"

...was my suggested text to add to the readme in [this pull request](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/pull/5).

Comment: Harry, another issue about use, is that some locale has to already be in focus in the map canvas. A brand new project will often cause the plugin to return an error since it has no extents to work from.

Answer (score 1):

in 1.8 there is a plugin by name plugin installer may be checking it will give you the option of fetch python plugin and you can install it automatically

Answer (score 1):

Please click Menu **Plugins** --> **Fetch Python Plugins** --> Type **Openlayers Plugin** in Filter row's --> then you will find **Openlayers Plugin** --> select it --> click **Install/Upgrade plugin**.