# Instructions for installing Sextante plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante

As a follow-up to the [question I recently asked on PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63573/looking-for-pyqgis-syntax-examples-guide), can someone please point me to a document, webpage or thread that provides me with step-by-step instructions as to how to install an external QGIS plugin?

I've read through the  [manual's "Loading an external QGIS plugin" section](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.8.0_user_guide_en.pdf) and I have not succeeded in decrypting either of the following two threads:
[How to install Openlayers plugin on Qgis 1.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30132/how-to-install-openlayers-plugin-on-qgis-1-8)
or
[How to install QGIS 1.8 plugin Georeferencer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/how-to-install-qgis-1-8-plugin-georeferencer?rq=1)

I tried to add the Sextante repository https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git in the plugin manager, but it remains empty under the plugins tab.  I'm obviously missing some fundamental piece here.  I also cannot find my plugins directory (C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa... ????).

Any help is much appreciated,

thanks, mike

Comment: and regarding your link. What you tried to add is a GIT repository. You need a special client to access those repos and they are normally not needed by normal users. The official QGIS repo is  within the main QGIS plugin server http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Comment: Thank you @Curlew.  Unfortunately, my Official QGIS Repository remains empty and the plugin Installer shows only 6 plugins available as opposed to the 155 shown below...

Comment: I had a similar problem once in a QGIS workshop i gave. Back then one of the participants solved the problem by re-installing QGIS via the OSGEO4W installer (-> advanced Install). And you might want to install the current dev version (qgis-dev) as well as sextante is already included here

Comment: Are you trying to do this from behind a proxy server at work?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that may be the problem.  I'll update once I (hopefully) resolve.

Comment: got it, that proxy server was the issue.  Thanks @Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Install

Sextante is in the official plugin repository.
Go to Plugins => Fetch Plugins, look for Sextante in the list, select it and click install.

[image]

In case it is not in the list, the main repository is probably missing. Go to the Repositories tab and add the following URL:
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

[image]

### Proxy Settings

In case there are still not all plugins showing up, make sure, that the proxy settings in Settings => Options => Network are properly set up.

### Enable

You also have to make sure it is enabled. Go to Plugins => Manage Plugins, and tick the Sextante entry in the list.

### Newer version

The latest version for QGIS 1.8 is from January 2013. Since then, a lot of improvement has been made, but is only available with the current Nightly (aka master, 1.9, 2.0) and is there installed by default. Be aware that this is an unstable version of QGIS but may bring improvements.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when I go to Fetch Plugins and click on QGIS Official Respository it is empty...  The url matches yours exactly.  It is empty with the "any status" criteria selected.

Comment: btw I'm running on an archaic Windows Xp 32-bit.  Might this have something to do with it?

Comment: Thank you again, but my QGIS Python Plugin Installer says there are only 6 plugins available while yours says 155 available.  What am I missing?? I just downloaded qgis last week.

Comment: @mikeLdub Are you using QGIS master/dev or 1.8? In master, Sextante is included by default and you don't need to install it. Just enable it in Plugin Manager.

Comment: @underdark, I have 1.8 installed.

Comment: If you need a proxy to access the network, make sure it is properly configured in Settings => Options => Network

Comment: ok, I set up the configurations to the proxy server and I now have access to all the 150+ plugins.  Thanks for your help @MattiasKuhn